# **dotnet core console** app: ConfigureAwait(true)

Tags: c#, async-await, configureawait

Below a **dotnet core console** app (I guess same if **aspnet core/webapi** apps).

```
class Program {
    static async Task Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"Simple Async #1. Thread ID: {Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId}"); # OK, thread Id = 1, the main thread.
        await Task.Delay(100).ConfigureAwait(true);
        Console.WriteLine($"Simple Async #2. Thread ID: {Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId}"); # Huh?  thread Id = 4?!? I thought ConfigureAwait(true) would instruct we'd return to original main thread after await?

    }
}
```

I am confused why at #2, Thread Id = 4. I expect Thread Id = 1 as ConfigureAwait(true) should give instruction we return to original context after **await**?

I am guessing, for **dotnet core console** and **aspnet core/webapi**'s, synchronization context is not captured by default, so ConfigureAwait(**true**) doesn't actually have any effect on which thread the continuation runs on. It only takes effect in WPF, Winform..etc

For same argument, this would why with ConfigureAwait(**false**), we may see continuation tasks still running in new thread (not necessarily): it may still get executed in the same thread.

So essentially for **dotnet core console** and **aspnet core/webapi**'s, ConfigureAwait does not guarantee whether it return or not return whether you set to True/False?

Am I mistaken?

Comment: `ConfigureAwait(true)` only returns you to the original thread in the presence of a synchronization-context. Such a context does not exist in a Console program. Generally speaking, you'll only encounter them in interactive desktop GUI contexts like WInForms and WPF.

Comment: Yes when succh SynchronizationContext is non-existent in dotnet core console apps, ConfigureAwait is essentially making random decision which thread to execute continuation tasks?

Comment: Yes, because control will return to the thread-pool before returning to `Main` - and inside the thread-pool there will be [at least a handful of idling threads by default](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/threading/the-managed-thread-pool), so the runtime is free to use any of those threads to return you back to your `Main` method.